# Google Apps Script - updating Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I try to update a Google Form from Google Sheets.
There is one type of question that I can't find how to activate using Google Apps Script:
'Multiple choice grid'

As you can see in the picture, the is only one option for 'multiple choice'.

I found this article that presents the available types, maybe it can assist you:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type

CODE VERSION #2:

```
    const populateGoogleForms1 = () => {
      const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = 'sheet_name';
      const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = 'form_path';
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
  const [header, ...data] = ss
    .getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME)
    .getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues();

  const choices = {};
  header.forEach((title, i) => {
    choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);
  });

  FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID)
    .getItems()
    .map((item) => ({
      item,
      values: choices[item.getTitle()],
    }))
    .filter((values) => values)
    .forEach(({ item, values }) => {
      switch (item.getType()) {


case FormApp.ItemType.CheckboxGrid:
item.asCheckboxGridItem().setChoiceValues(values);
break;
case FormApp.ItemType.Checkbox:
item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values);
break;
case FormApp.ItemType.Grid:
item.asGridItem().setChoiceValues(values);
break;
case FormApp.ItemType.List:
item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
break;
case FormApp.ItemType.MultipleChoice:
item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
break;
case FormApp.ItemType.MultipleChoiceGrid:
item.asMultipleChoiceGridItem().setChoiceValues(values);
break;



        default:
        // ignore item
      }
    });
  ss.toast('Google Form Updated !!');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 Grid options available in Google Forms, multiple choice grid and checkbox grid.

If you want to get the type of the multiple choice grid, use `GRID` property

> **GRID**
>
> A question item, presented as a grid of columns and rows, that allows the respondent to select one choice per row from a sequence of radio buttons.

I created a temporary form having multiple choice grid and checkbox grid only, I tried to log the form's items and the results are as follow:

```
4:25:02 AM  Notice  Execution started
4:25:04 AM  Info    GRID
4:25:04 AM  Info    CHECKBOX_GRID
4:25:03 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

---

### UPDATE

When you use [asCheckboxGridItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asCheckboxGridItem()),It will return a [CheckboxGridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item) Class which contains all methods available for that class, setChoiceValues() is not available in CheckboxGridItem Class. You need to use [setColumns(columns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#setcolumnscolumns) for the choices or [setRows(rows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#setrowsrows) for the questions.

**Sample Code:**

```
function updateForm() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("1AFCnzOrsdJfZ5VZIdVahVZvMdbXm3fOIZnGxxxx");
  var items = form.getItems();
  var questions = ["Question1", "Question2"];
  var answers = ["True", "False"];
  items.forEach(item =>{
    //var choices = item.asListItem().getChoices();
    //var choices = item.asGridItem();

    switch(item.getType()){
      case FormApp.ItemType.GRID:
        var choices = item.asGridItem();
        choices.setColumns(answers);
        choices.setRows(questions);
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX_GRID:
        var choices = item.asCheckboxGridItem();
        choices.setColumns(answers);
        choices.setRows(questions);
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

### OUTPUT:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: hi, Thanks a lot for the response. I tried to do this but I get failures. Attached an example in the body of the question.

Comment: You cannot get the multiple choice grid and checkbox grid items using [asListItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#aslistitem). You should use [asGridItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asGridItem()) for multiple choice grid item or [asCheckboxGridItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asCheckboxGridItem())

Comment: appreciate your willingness to assist!  I tried to do that, but it fails to update my Google Form.  Attaching my revised code (Version2), following your kind notes

Comment: When you use [asCheckboxGridItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asCheckboxGridItem()),It will return a [CheckboxGridItem Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item) which contains all methods available for that class, setChoiceValues()  is not available in CheckboxGridItem Class. You need to use [setColumns(columns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#setcolumnscolumns) or  [setRows(rows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#setrowsrows)